# Knowing when backups were launched

Tags: debian, hp

We have got here HP DataProtector for backups.

Once in a while I see backups (still) running launched by a sysop, and I wish to know when they were launched / for how long has them been running.

Is it possible?

I know I seen on this `ps` `-start 1501495248`

```
$px ax
31899 ?        SNs    0:28 /opt/omni/lbin/vbda -bmaname HP:Ultrium 4-SCSI_10_xxx(2) -type 2 -start 1501495248 -level 0 -access 1 0 -protection 2 604800 -name /h
31900 ?        SN     0:00 /opt/omni/lbin/vbda -bmaname HP:Ultrium 4-SCSI_10_xxx(2) -type 2 -start 1501495248 -level 0 -access 1 0 -protection 2 604800 -name /h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ps` command can show you the start time or elapsed time:

```
$ ps -O start,lstart,etime
  PID  STARTED                  STARTED     ELAPSED S TTY          TIME COMMAND
 7827 15:18:42 Tue Aug  1 15:18:42 2017       00:00 R pts/12   00:00:00 ps -O
10413   Jul 16 Sun Jul 16 17:36:12 2017 15-21:42:30 S pts/12   00:00:07 bash
```

Comment: Nicely remembered too, was forgetting that.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible to know when that backup was launched. 
The time is effectively after `-start` and it is in the Unix epoch format (or Unix time or POSIX time or Unix timestamp).

So with:

```
$date -d @1501495248
Mon Jul 31 11:00:48 WEST 2017
```

You know that backup was launched yesterday at the end of the morning.

You can also see the file `/var/opt/omni/log/inet.log`

and see the last entry as:

```
Mon Jul 31 11:00:49 2017 [ADMINISTRATOR.XXXX@xxxx.xxx.xxx] : vbda
```